# "Не число" NaN при вычислении кубического корня через Math.Pow

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System;

namespace дом_работа
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write(" Введите значение x = ");
            double x = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write(" Введите значение y = ");
            double y = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            double Sum = Math.Pow(Math.Sin(Math.Pow(x * y - Math.Pow(x, y), 2)), 2) - Math.Pow(1 - (Math.Pow(x, 2)), 1.0 / 3.0);
            Console.WriteLine($"sin^2(x*y-x^y)^2-√^3(1-x^2)= {Sum:F3}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

почему-то из за кубического корня возникают проблемы, так как если `x` будет больше 1 то программа выводит в консоль не число, в чем может быть проблема ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Насколько я в курсе, `Math.Pow(x, y)` для не целого `y` реализован так `exp(y * ln(x))`, где `ln(x)` при `x <= 0` вычислить нельзя, потому что математически результат - [комплексное число](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE). У вас `x = -3`, `y = 1/3`.

Попробуйте так

```cs
double z = 1 - Math.Pow(x, 2);
double Sum = Math.Pow(Math.Sin(Math.Pow(x * y - Math.Pow(x, y), 2)), 2) - Math.Pow(Math.Abs(z), 1.0 / 3.0) * (z < 0 ? -1 : 1);
```

```
Введите значение x = 2
Введите значение y = 3
sin^2(x*y-x^y)^2-√^3(1-x^2)= 2,015
```

Comment: Условие (z < 0 ? -1 : 1) что делает ?  Что означают в нем "?, :"

Comment: @Alex если `z < 0`, то `-1`, иначе `1` - [тернарный оператор](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)